# How can i use one HttpURLConnection download many pictures from one website?

Tags: android, http, networking, httpurlconnection

My app should download many pictures from one website,the number is more than 200.So if i put this below code in a for(int i = 0; i++ ; i < 200),it looks not nice,the connection should connect and disconnect every time.

So anybody have some good suggestions?

```java
URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
conn = (HttpURLConnection)(imageUrl.openConnection());
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BitmapFactory.Options ops = new BitmapFactory.Options();
ops.inSampleSize = inSample;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, ops);
is.close();
conn.disconnect();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since each image have a separate url, connection have to open and closed. There are no alternatives for this code.

Comment: All the picture in the same website,so their main domain is the same,can i make a connection with the main domain,then set the different path

Comment: I don't think that is possible either.

Comment: Your answer completely ignores the existence of HTTP keep-alive. Your first sentence is therefore a *non sequitur.*

Answer (score 1):

URLConnection pooling happens behind the scenes. You don't have to worry about it yourself.